# How to show, edit or delete widget/property of widget in ListView.builder when a specific item widget is pressed on flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I have made a custom widget that fetches the data from the API and displays it using ListView.builder method in flutter. ListView.builder returns a widget, so I have made custom widget 'menuLoadedList' that is returned by ListView.builder to display the data from the API. Inside this custom 'menuLoadedList' widget there are many widget, to display number, to display item name and GestureDetector widget to detect user tap, onTap(). Activity looks like this:
[ListView.builder displaying data from the API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtB9D.png)

I have only designed this one list [ListView design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4oLY.png), which is used by listview.builder method to display all the data in the database.

```
child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _thisMenu(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                // load the data here to display it in the list view
                print("Data is here");
                return ListView.builder(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.menus.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    Menu menuu = snapshot.data;
                    MenuElement menuItem = menuu.menus[index];
                    return menuLoadedList(menuItem, index);
                  },
                );
              }

              ///when the API cannot fetch the data properly
              /// should design some error handling mechanism, custom widget to displau "Oops! Something went wrong" with a image
              else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("${snapshot.error}");
              }

              /// when the data is still loading, for loading screen
              else {
                print("we are still loading");
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: 6,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return menuListShimmer();
                  },
                );
              }
            },
          ),
```

And the custom widget to display the data is implemented with: -

```
 Widget menuLoadedList(MenuElement menuItem, int index) {
return DefaultTextStyle(
  style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16.0),
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        //column for the list view to display menu name, price and displying button to add, remove and show the quantity of the order
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            //first row shows the menu name and price
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                // shows the menu name
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text(menuItem.name),
                  ),
                ),
                //show the menu price
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text("Rs. " + menuItem.price.toString()),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            //second row shows the add, remove and show the quantity of the order
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                //first button shows the add button
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    // when the users taps the minus button
                    onTap: () {
                      print(index);
                      _addItemToOder(false, index, "Spicy", 5);
                    },
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.remove_circle,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Text("$counter"), // this needs to be updated
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      print(index);
                      _addItemToOder(true, index, "Spicy", 5);
                      setState(() {
                        
                      });
                    },
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.add_circle,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Visibility(
              child: Container(
                // height: 30,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                child: const TextField(
                  autofocus: false,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 12.0),
                  //defines the charcter of test field for the remarks textfield
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    isDense: true,
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide:
                          BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 2.0),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide:
                          BorderSide(color: Colors.green, width: 2.0),
                    ),
                    hintText: "Add your remarks",
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              visible: showRemarksField,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

}

On the custom widget implementation there is Text widget with comment this need to be updated. When the app is called upon with onTap method, how to update the Text widget of that particular Listview.builder item only out of many other.

**My question is:-** When I press the plus or minus button in any of the widget item within the custom widget, how can I update only the Text widget its property/value within that custom widget in the listview.builder ? How can I keep the track of the button of the list item in the listview.builder that I have pressed and update the text widget within that list item only?

**Note:-** When I press any one plus or minus button in the list every text value is updated. I cannot change any specific text widget within custom widget.

Answer (score 0):

// generate Blank list on top your class : -->  List priceChange = [];

// on future builder :

```
    Menu menuu = snapshot.data;
    MenuElement menuItem = menuu.menus[index];
    priceChange = List.generate(snapshot.data.menus.length, (index){
      return 0.0; // or snaphot.data.menu. --> where u put price data
    });
```

// on widget maybe you can pass bool to manipulate rendered ui :

```
return menuLoadedList(menuItem, index, List<double> priceChange, bool userTap){
      // in child ----->
      child: Text("Rs. " + userTap[index]? priceChange[index]: menuItem.price.toString());
    };
```

and manipulate that Ui based list (priceChange) :

```
    setState(() {
    //remove old data
    priceChange.removeAt(index);
    //inset new
    priceChange.insert(index, 100);
  });
```

i prefer use [bloc pattern](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/gettingstarted) for this kind of logic

Comment: Yes, I have used futurebuilder. I am talking about the UI element here, not the List class in flutter. Here ListView.builder generates the custom widget that I have created to display the data. How can I modify that particular custom widget that ListView.builder have created out of many?

Comment: I have updated my question with some code snippet and some more explanation.

Comment: i think bool should be a list too

Comment: well my point is you can separate ui and logic with bloc pattern management, we can make it to 3 type of state : loading state, state need to be future, and final state for ui, bloc basically a stream to different class (ui, state, event)

Answer (score 0):

Add 'counter' property into MenuElement when call setState it still values edit